# Google Sheets Stating - "array arguments to sumifs are different size"

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I'm receiving an error on google sheets...array arguments to sumifs are different size

I'm trying to reference a tab on my google sheets "OTR Expenses" and the formula is not working.

Column D is Expenses
Column H is Category,
A2 is Category Name matching with Column H
Column F is Project Name
B2 Is matching project name as column F.

```
=SUMIFS('OTR Expenses'!D1:219,'OTR Expenses'!H1:219,A2,'OTR Expenses'!F1:219,B2)
```

I was expecting to see an overall budget... If Project "X" and category "X" are used, what is my total sum?

Comment: Change `D1:219` to `D1:D219` & the same with columns ***H*** & ***F***